# How can I reorder strings of text using regex and javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

For example, I have this in a textarea:

```
 <textarea>
   <div class="sections">
     <div class="item" id="apple">
        Apple
     </div>
     <div class="item" id="blueberry">
        Blueberry
     </div>
     <div class="item" id="orange">
        Orange
     </div>
   </div>
 </textarea>
```

Using regex, I want to reorder the string like so:

```
  <textarea>
    <div class="sections">
      <div class="item" id="orange">
         Orange
      </div>
      <div class="item" id="blueberry">
         Blueberry
      </div>
      <div class="item" id="apple">
         Apple
      </div>
    </div>
  </textarea>
```

I thought about doing something like this, but it's not doing it correctly:

```
var string = $("textarea").val() // note: I want to keep this as a string
new_content = string.replace(/<div class="sections">(.*)<\/div>/, '<div class="sections"></div>') // remove inner content
new_content = new_content + string.match(/<div.*id="orange">(.*)<\/div>/)[0]
new_content = new_content + string.match(/<div.*id="blueberry">(.*)<\/div>/)[0] 
new_content = new_content + string.match(/<div.*id="apple">(.*)<\/div>/)[0]
```

Any idea?

Comment: HTML isn't a regular language, you can't really parse it with a regular expression

Comment: Is this your real input? I mean div contents are equal to their ids?

Comment: The div contents are some sample text :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the proper regexes you were looking for.  You were assuming .* matched the newlines which is not the default for javascript.

You can read more about it here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

```js
$(() => {
  var string = $("textarea").val() // note: I want to keep this as a string
  
  new_content = string.match(/\s*<div.*?class="sections">/g)[0];
  new_content += string.match(/\s*<div.*?id="orange">(.|\s)*?<\/div>/g)[0]
  new_content += string.match(/\s*<div.*?id="blueberry">(.|\s)*?<\/div>/g)[0] 
  new_content += string.match(/\s*<div.*?id="apple">(.|\s)*?<\/div>/g)[0]
  new_content += string.match(/.*>(\s*<\/div>)/s)[1];
  
  $('textarea').val(new_content);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <textarea>
   <div class="sections">
     <div class="item" id="apple">
        Apple
     </div>
     <div class="item" id="blueberry">
        Blueberry
     </div>
     <div class="item" id="orange">
        Orange
     </div>
   </div>
 </textarea>
```

Comment: This is excellent Leinardo! Thank you so much!! I was about to close this topic because I saw the negative votes and didn't think this could be solved with regex, but I'm very glad I saw your solution before I did so. Thank you so much again Leinardo!! :)